# Apache cordova and visual studio; Good Choice?

Tags: apache, cordova, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app

What would be a better option Apache cordova based application or Xamarin. Do we have any market analysis or tool popularity matrix by which one can choose their development path.

Answer (score 2):

There are pros and cons for both approaches, you should make your own choice based on your needs and expectations.

You can find load of articles related to this. From the top results in Google:
    [Picking between Xamarin and Apache Cordova](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nzdev/archive/2014/12/22/picking-between-xamarin-and-apache-cordova.aspx)
    [Comparing Xamarin and Cordova on Visual Studio 2015](http://ridilabs.net/post/2015/07/05/Comparing-Xamarin-and-Cordova-on-Visual-Studio-2015.aspx)
    [Which one is better: Xamarin or Apache Cordova?](http://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-Xamarin-or-Apache-Cordova)

I would suggest you also consider what technology you and the devs involved feel more comfortable with, since the ramp up effort should also be taken into account.